# Instrumenting Array via java.lang.Object

Tags: java, instrumentation

I am currently working on a platform which makes heavy use of dynamic byte code modification routines via the ASM library. I have been able to successfully instrument all required system classes apart from the array class. (i.e String[], int[], etc) this is because the array class is, itself, a dynamic type thus there is actually no class file in the rt.jar to instrument as far as i'm aware.

However, It did occur to me that even the array type extends java.lang.Object so although modifying the Object class would be less than ideal, not least because it would cause any changes to be propagated to all sub classes, it would possibly allow me to indirectly add an extra primitive field to the array class which, incidentally, is all i'm seeking to achieve.

Aside from the obvious caveats I've mentioned would this cause any other platform related problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of instrumenting Object, the simplest thing to do is replace it with a compiled version of your choice.  Assuming this works, you can instrument it to make it more portable.

Note: I have found JVMs don't like Object to have additional methods (If you add more than one you get strange errors)

Comment: Yes that's in a sense what I've been doing with all system classes as its not possible to dynamically transform them as they are loaded before my application and the instrumentation framework does not permit you to change the structure of a class once its been loaded. Have you managed to successfully add one or more fields to an Object without any problems in the past then?

Comment: I haven't tried to add fields, but if it going to work you can add it to a copy of the source and put this on the prepended boot class path. Even if it works on one VM I suspect it wont work on all of them.  BTW To add code to array via Object you shouldn't need to add a field.

Comment: As stated in my original post I'm only trying to add a single field to the Object class as suppose to adding code.It would seem like this unfortunately would be more trouble than its worth as according to the info here: http://old.nabble.com/Add-a-Field-to-java.lang.Object-td31802603.html Parts of the JVM rely on hardcoded Object offsets as such adding a field would mean recalculating these offsets and placing the values everywhere they are required in the corresponding c++ .h files.

Comment: If you add a field, it will be added to every sub-class.  Adding a method has less impact. As you say different JVMs will have different limitations.

Comment: You are correct, like I say in my OP adding a field to object is less than Ideal but I need to be able to add a Field to the array class & can't think of any other way. The platform i'm working on assigns every object an Id which is stored in this extra field however, array is a special case as I'm unable to get direct access to array class byte code. At present I'm just associating ids with array objects using a map but I guess I would have much preferred to store this information directly to the array instances. Looks now like this will not be possible without a great deal of extra work.

Comment: @GilesThompson Your only option may be to have an array wrapper which stores the extra information and the array.

Answer (score 3):

You may have difficulty getting and setting the field.

The descriptions in the JVM specification for the [`getfield`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.getfield) and [`putfield`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.putfield) instructions (if I understand them correctly) state that they aren't to be used on arrays.  To quote, for `getfield`:

> The type of objectref must not be an array type.

and `putfield`:

> The class of objectref must not be an array.

However, 'If some constraint (a "must" or "must not") in an instruction description is not satisfied at runtime, the behavior of the Java virtual machine is undefined', so it might just work.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem as I can inject a public field into the Object and then just access it directly.

Comment: I think it would still be undefined behaviour since the dynamic type of the object is an array type.

Comment: I think you may be right. In any event it seems that numerous C++ based JVM modules would need to be updated in order to get this to function properly as hard-coded Object offsets are implicitly used by the JVM platform in some places. I have up voted the answer as the JVM specification info provided was useful.

Comment: @GilesThompson, if you just want to keep track of some metadata about some array instances, it might be sufficient to use them as keys in a `WeakHashMap`.

Comment: That's exactly the approach I've had to take in this instance.